# Oracle Apex Session State update from JS

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am updating my session variables using Javascript.
Page->Javascript->Execute when page loads.

```
apex.server.process ( "Update Session", {
    pageItems: "#P1_ITEM1, P1_ITEM2"
    }, {
        dataType: "text"
        , success: function( pData ) { 
          //pData should contain VALID or INVALID - alert it

          if ( pData === 'INVALID' ) {
            // do something here when the result is invalid
              alert('Invalid Data: Contact Admin:');
          };
        }
    } );
```

}

I am using P1_ITEM1 and P1_ITEM2 to populate data in a region of the page. The problem is: the region which uses the session value seems to load before the execution of the JS code due to which older values of the items are used instead of the new value. Is there any way around it, so that the region loads only after the session values are updated?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I can't add comment. Try to put proccess in Pre-Rendering section of the page(before Header, before regions...). You can try with condition on change of P1_ITEM1, P1_ITEM2 item to refresh region but the first solution should be enough.